# Prosody XMPP server on WSL 2: A record points to unknown address

Tags: networking, dns, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2, xmpp

I'm trying to set up a Prosody XMPP server, and I'm wanting to put it on my existing Windows machine running WSL 2. I've followed the docs on Prosody's site and most steps succeeded without any trouble. However, now that I've got it to the point where it has certificates and is running, I'm unable to connect to the server using any XMPP client.

Additionally, running `prosodyctl check` shows that DNS is not resolving correctly:

```
Checking DNS for host chat.cooperplanet.com...
    cooperplanet.com. A record points to unknown address [my-public-ip]
    Host cooperplanet.com. does not seem to resolve to this server (IPv4/IPv6)
    No targets for chat.cooperplanet.com appear to resolve to this server.
```

Interestingly, the domain, subdomain, and IP address all seem correct to me here, but clearly prosody is finding a problem with the DNS.

Here's what I've tried:

- Double-checked my DNS rules
- Double-checked my port forwarding rules on my router
- Set up Windows Firewall rules for Prosody C2S and S2S ports
- Also tried setting the firewall rules using `netsh advfirewall` in Powershell
- Verified that all necessary processes are using the correct permissions
- Verified that I can reach the server externally and internally by pinging ip/domain name
- Verified that Prosody has access to the SSL certificates and is loading them
- Tried setting up WSL 2 in mirrored networking mode
- Tried connecting to the server using multiple XMPP clients on multiple OSes, both inside and outside of my local network.

Any ideas what could be causing this, or further ideas to narrow where my problem might be? Or is there any issue with running Prosody within WSL that I may not know about?

Thanks in advance!